# My Passport Ultra is plugged in, and I can access it's properties, but I cannot access the files on there

Tags: external-hard-drive

My Passport Ultra is plugged in, and I can access it's properties, but I cannot access the files on there. It doesn't auto open anymore, and when I go to My PC, it doesn't even say that my passport is connected. I have 1.5 TB of files on there and I am really desperate to get it working again. What do I do!?

Comment: Do you see the drive if you go to `Computer management` > `Disk management`?

Comment: If your handle is any reflection, you should post a screenshot of DiskMgmt.msc

Answer (score 0):

How does it appear in Disk Management? I'd recommend you to try [uninstalling and reinstalling it as a device from Device Manager](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725782.aspx) and see if that will help your system to detect it properly upon a reboot. Another thing you should try is testing the external using WD's Data LifeGuard Diagnostics and determine the health and SMART status. Just make sure you run both the QUICK and the EXTENDED test. [Here's a link to the WD utilities](http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=xJLo6A).